# Can't get query string in ajax call

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, ajax

I'm developing a plugin that exports to a PDF your current posts view in the admin panel.

Suppose you're in a post type "product", then the url must be: `edit.php?post_type=product`.

What I want is to get that query string (can be something more difficult, `post_typeproduct&area=new-your` for example), and set a loop (in an ajax call) to create and show a PDF.

The problem is that I'm trying with:

`$wp->request, $wp->query_string, get_queried_object(), $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GLOBALS['wp_query']`, but non of above works, all are empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're trying to pass data between PHP (WordPress) and Javascript (AJAX), use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing but an AJAX request is a ___new___ request to the server. Any query strings you want that AJAX request to have access to you need to include when you make the request.

Comment: Well I just want to get the current "admin screen" query, if I'm watching the posts' archive, in the admin panel, the URL is .../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post, so  then I want to get that Query.